# best way to map back from numpy array to pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have a time series like following:

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = [datetime(2011, 1, 2), datetime(2011, 1, 5), datetime(2011, 1, 7), datetime(2011, 1, 8), datetime(2011, 1, 10), datetime(2011, 1, 12)]
ts = pd.DataFrame({"a":np.random.randn(6),"b":np.random.randn(6)}, index=dates)
ts.iloc[2,0]=np.nan
ts.iloc[3,1]=np.nan
```

[image]

so it happens on many instances that we need to convert it to numpy array, with nonull values, and do different processis, like NN, etc...

```
ts.dropna().values
```

[image]

Now for example lets say that a new column c is generated from numpy array calculations(clustering, NN,...):

[image]

what is the best way to add this to original df so it becomes like:

[image]

in other words in this workflow:

1- start with pandas dataframe multifeature time series

2- remove nulls

3- calculate a new array from 2 (classification, NN, ...)

4- adding the array created in 3 to the original dataframe in step 1 (how to do this properly?)

I know that some might say we can stick with pandas for the entire process, but lets say the table gets 3 dimensional that we need to convert it to numpy array.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `isna/notna` to mask your data, then `.loc` to assign back:

```
valids = ts.notna().all(axis=1)

# equivalent to ts.dropna().values
data = ts[valids].to_numpy()

# do stuff
preds = KMeans().fit_predict(data)
# preds = [0, 0, 0, 1]

# assign prediction back
# ravel in the case your predictions are 2D as shown
ts.loc[valids, 'pred'] = preds.ravel()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. drop your NaNs from the dataframe and assign the index to a variable.
2. create a pandas dataframe containing `c`, with this index
3. left join this new dataframe to the original